# What are the steps to publishing and accessing a website?

Tags: web, dns, virtual-server

Hi I have been working on asp.net for a while. I am wondering if I want to launch my own website made using asp.net visual studio, how do I go about it?

My question is about if I should be buying a server or use a web virtual web host. Which one of these is better? Do I need to purchase a domain name separately or I can host that on my own?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have asked a fair few questions in one there! I will do my best to give you an overall answer.

To make a website "public" you need some form of hosting, you would then place the website files (compiled .net website) onto the server and it would become public.

There are hundreds of hosts out there, a quick search in google for "Windows web hosting" will give you plenty of options. Ensure you compare a few so that you get good value for money.

As you say you will also need a domain name to "point" at the hosting, which ever provider you pick will generally offer you a price that includes your domain name of choice.

Comment: do I need to get myself a server?

Comment: As I said in my answer, for a simple website you can just buy some shared hosting. Such as that provided by sites that you would find doing a simple search on google for "web hosting". Unless you plan a very large site with a lot of users you won't need a dedicated server (or even a VPS) for some time. Better to start small and cheap.

Comment: no worries, just remember to accept answers on your questions!